# Thymeleaf: Iterate over enum values and use them in a list filter

Tags: html, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am struggling using enum values in list filters in Thymeleaf.

I know how to iterate over enum values and how to compare them against constant values. However, I want to compare it against a 'variable' value. How can I achieve it?

In my example below, I want to iterate trough all colors (enum) and then filter a list of cars by the current color enum and display their names.

How do I specify the list filter in the second `<div>` correctly?

```
<div th:each="currentColorEnum : ${T(de.my.enum.color).values()}">
    <div th:each="currentCar, carStatus : ${model.carList.?[#this.colorEnum eq __${currentColorEnum}__]}">                  
        <textarea th:field="*{carList[__${carStatus.index}__].carName}"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Current error message:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'red' cannot be found on object of type 'de.my.class.car' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for preprocessing in this case.  It's failing because `${model.carList.?[#this.colorEnum eq __${currentColorEnum}__]}` resolves to `${model.carList.?[#this.colorEnum eq red]}`.  Which means it looking for cars where `car.colorEnum == car.red` -- hence the error `field 'red' cannot be found on object of type 'de.my.class.car'`.

Your Thymeleaf should look something like:

```
<div th:each="currentColorEnum : ${T(de.my.enum.color).values()}">
    <div th:each="currentCar, carStatus : ${model.carList.?[colorEnum eq #root.currentColorEnum]}">                  
        <textarea th:field="*{carList[__${carStatus.index}__].carName}"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```